# How to get the identity claim encoding types of windows and forms authentication providers using API?

Tags: sharepoint, authentication, provider, claims

We have to get all the claims providers associated with a web application and its identity claim encoding type using API.

For example:

If the identity claim of windows authentication is user name and the user name is a string, then we should get "i:0#.w".

If the identity claim of forms authentication is email and the provider name is "fba" , then we should get "i:0!.f|fba|".

The below link shows us to get all claims providers associated with a web application, but how do we get the identity claim encoding type of each provider?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650432(v=office.14).aspx#SP_WCP_Tip3

```
using (SPSite theSite = new SPSite("http://someContosoUrl"))
{

   // Get the web application.

    SPWebApplication wa = theSite.WebApplication; 

    // Get the zone for the site.

    SPUrlZone theZone = theSite.Zone;

    // Get the settings that are associated with the zone.

    SPIisSettings theSettings = wa.GetIisSettingsWithFallback(theZone);

    // Get the list of authentication providers that are associated with the zone.

    foreach (SPAuthenticationProvider prov in 

        theSettings.ClaimsAuthenticationProviders)

    {

   // Need to get the identity claims encoding type using the SPAuthenticationProvider

    }
}
```

Is windows authentication's identity claim encoding type always i.0#.w or the identity claim is always the user name?

Thanks & Regards,

Kalai.